# Help center links to a "closed as off topic" question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

1. [Hey, this is a nice site.](http://english.stackexchange.com) I have a question to ask, but I want to make sure I do it right.
2. [Ahh, the Help Center.](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) I hope it has some useful guidance for asking questions.
3. ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) —oh no, my question is simple and basic, and is therefore "off-topic" here.  But isn't there anywhere I can go for an answer to my question?
4. "**Where can I find answers to simple and basic questions?** If your question is simple and can probably be easily answered by looking it up, then you may find common online internet resources to be of some help. View [our list of community recommended resources](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/what-are-your-favorite-english-language-tools) to find some that may be of help to you." Why that sounds like just what I'm looking for. I'll click ri-i-ight about here...
5. ["closed as off topic"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/what-are-your-favorite-english-language-tools)
6. [image]

Answer (score 5):

The question was closed to prevent further answers from being added, and also to discourage similar resource requests, which are essentially list-type questions and therefore off-topic. However, it is a useful resource, so it was kept for reference purposes.

If I have incorrectly assumed your question, please edit your post to ask one.

Comment: Shouldn't it be locked instead? "Closed as off topic" sends a contradictory message.

Comment: I agree with phenry here. That thread would look much better as “protected to prevent ‘Thanks!’, etc.” (or however the phrasing of protected threads goes). Much less confusing to a new user who might not know exactly what different types of locked/protected/frozen threads appear like.

Comment: @phenry But it is off topic. So that's not a contradictory message.

Comment: I agree with Matt. I'm not seeing the contradiction.

Comment: Would it be off-topic on Meta as well? We could migrate it here, and then protect it; that would (hopefully) make everyone happy. @Matt, I don’t think it’s so much whether the message is really, logically contradictory or not; but more that anyone who is likely to _need to see_ the page, by definition, are also quite likely to perceive it as contradictory or at least confusing. Most users who know the site/system well enough to realise it’s not really contradictory are not very likely to ever need to be pointed to the page at all.

Comment: @Janus We do have other resource lists here on Meta. It could probably be migrated. I'll look into it.

Comment: Migrating it to Meta makes sense to me, certainly more so than closing it as "off-topic."